# Cloud Run + Apache + Load Balancer: How to get paths right?

Tags: apache, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-run

Good morning, I am moving my PHP + Apache application from Compute Engine VM to Google Cloud Run, I managed to get the Cloud Run service up and running and somewhat working, but I want it to be avaible at [www.mydomainexample.com.br/app/something](http://www.mydomainexample.com.br/app/something), when I set the Load Balancer to do "https://www.mydomainexample.com.br/app/something/* -> Cloud Run service", it hits Apache running on my Cloud Run service, just as expected, but it returns 404 because the load balancer requests "/app/something/" from Apache, which doesn't exist since I want the load balancer to just send the users from that URL + path to the start page of my application that's running on Apache, that should be my base URL.

So I need to know which Google Cloud Platform solution or Apache conf directive would be ideal to do what I want. Apache's "Alias" didn't work and I was never sure if it was really the right, clever and beautier way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform [path rewrite with HTTPS load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-url-rewrite).

- In the host and path rules, click on advanced
- set the default rules (any path, any domain) and then add new host and path rules
- From there add a path rules

[image]

- And configure it like this

[image]

Comment: Nice, you helped me again, I remember you from that other question that I asked weeks ago. Thank you very much, again. :)

Comment: Hello, what if I want to access directories inside of /app/something/?

Comment: Normally, no issue, only the prefix is replaced. But I never tested!!

Comment: Perfect, it works. But I realized that if the URL doesn't have a slash at its very end, the redirect doesn't go as expected. I also realized that HTTP URLs are not upgraded to HTTPS. Are this 2 issues possible to fix? I have tried to play around with the Path rewrite prefix a little bit, but wasn't able to actually fix.

Comment: You mean this URL `/app/something`? If so, add it as another path in the `Paths` field

Comment: Yes, I did this, but if I have `/app/something/somethingelse` then it redirects to mydomain/somethingelse

Comment: And it's not what you want?

Comment: No, because something like `mydomainexample.com.br/something/admin` is redirecting to `mydomainexample.com.br/admin`, which does not exist. Unless I add the slash at the end.

Comment: Notice that my current Paths are `/app/something/*` and `/app/something` + Path prefix rewrite equal to `/`

Comment: You can only configure the prefix with Load Balancers. For the suffix, you need to update your Apache (and I don't know how) or your app to accept these paths.